# Cross-thread operation not valid in parent control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, invalidoperationexception

I am using the following code to update a label in my class which extends `UserControl`:

```
private delegate void LabelChanger(bool signedIn);

public bool SignedIn
{
    get { return _signedIn; }
    set
    {
        _signedIn = value;
        labelChanger(value);
    }
}

private void labelChanger(bool signedIn)
{
    if (label1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new LabelChanger(labelChanger), signedIn);
    }
    label1.Text = signedIn ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In";
}
```

The problem is that when the code gets to setting the label text, the UI is updated, however I get an `InvalidOperationException on a panel which is the label's parent. Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at InnerException and stack trace of this InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `label1.Text = signedIn ? "Sign Out" : "Sign In";` is executed even when you're in the wrong thread. You should enclose it with an `else {}`.